# Why does hatch not save the virtual environment in the same directory I am working in?

Tags: python, hatch

Why does hatch not save the virtual environment in the same directory I am working in? I went through the doc and couldn't find a way to achieve that. Maybe it makes sense that it's that way but I can't really think why.
Is there a way to create it in the project directory?
Or a good reason to not want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a tool like `hatch`, you are basically giving up precise control over the virtual environment in favor of letting `hatch` manage it for you; this includes letting `hatch` decide where to keep all such managed environments.

That said, `hatch` stores virtual environments in a specific data directory that you can specify using the `--data-dir` option to the `hatch` command itself.

```
$ mkdir hatchtest; cd hatchtest
$ ls
$ hatch --data-dir . env create
[...]
$ ls
env
```

(The default data directory likely varies from platform to platform; it's `~/Library/Application Support/hatch` on my macOS box.)